# ssrs join two datasets in same table with aggregate data

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, aggregate

I have a table in SSRS that showing the aggregate data from a dataset that is not aggregate. The data is aggregated by a row group.

I am trying to join another dataset which is aggregated to the first table. I got the following message: Aggregate function cannot be used for the destination or result expression parameter lookup function.

Can anyone show me how to join two datasets together in the same table is SSRS?

thanks

Comment: You should aggregate both datasets at the query level before bringing it into the report level.

Comment: are you doing `sum(lookup())`? if yes that wont work. try this link - http://salvoz.com/blog/2013/05/27/sum-result-of-ssrs-lookupset-function/